# C# modifing a string array in a foreach loop and changing the same array

Tags: c#

Maybe I asked this is a bad way so let me try to explain.

I have a **public static string[]**

```
public static string[] MyInfo {get;set;}
```

I set this via

```
MyInfo = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\myfile.txt");
```

What I want to do is a foreach on each of those lines and modify it based on x number of rules.  One the line has been modified change that exisiting line in MyInFo

so

```
foreach(string myI in MyInfo)
{
string modifiedLine = formatLineHere(myI);
//return this to MyInfo somehow.

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for:

```
for(int i = 0; i < MyInfo.Length; i++)
{
   MyInfo[i] = formatLineHere(MyInfo[i]);       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in a `foreach` loop. Use `for` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var myInfoList = new List<string>();
foreach (var myI in MyInfo)
{
    var modifiedLine = formatLineHere(myI);
    myInfoList.Add(modifiedLine);

}
MyInfo = myInfoList.ToArray();
```

**Update**

You will need a reference to System.Linq in order to use the ToList() and ToArray() extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

Or with Linq you could do:

```
MyInfo = MyInfo.Select(x => formatLineHere(x)).ToArray();
```